# ¿Cómo crear un archivo .txt a partir de una tabla en SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buenas, yo tengo una Query que me genera una tabla con una única columna y necesito generar un archivo .txt a partir de esta nueva tabla. Estuve buscando en internet, pero no encontré una solución; cualquier sugerencia será agradecida.

Answer (score 3):

Este proceso se puede realizar de varias formas. A continuación te ilustro algunos ejemplos:

**1. Utilizando la función xp_CmdShell, el archivo archivoSalida.txt debe existir**

```
DECLARE @Text AS VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Cmd AS VARCHAR(1000)
--Separador ;
SELECT @Text = COALESCE(@Text + ';', '') + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), 
[NombreColumna])
FROM [Tabla]

SET @Cmd = 'echo ' + @Text + ' > C:\archivoSalida.txt'
EXECUTE Master.dbo.xp_CmdShell @Cmd
```

**2. Utilizando sqlcmd**

Se crea el archivo .sql con la consulta

```
DECLARE @Text AS VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @Text = COALESCE(@Text + ';', '') + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), [NombreColumna])
FROM [Tabla]
PRINT @Text
```

Desde consola con permisos de administrador se ejecuta

```
sqlcmd -S nombreServidor -d baseDeDatos -i c:\archivoConsulta.sql -o c:\archivoSalida.txt
```